# Touch and hold in TableViewCell to show (tooltip) popover is it possible in iPhone?

Tags: ios, tooltip

According to image could you please advise me which function use to develop this feature?
i'm not sure, is it implement from UIPopover?
any idea, thank you.

source from Music.app iOS 5 beta 2

[image]

Comment: I posted a similar answer here, hope this helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26946626/2374877

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a UIGestureRecognizer. Specifically, what you are looking for is a [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

You should instantiate one and attach it to the view you would like to track the gesture on:

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

Then, in your handler method you would do the rest:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UILongGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

     if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {    

     } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

     }
 }
```

EDIT: for the popover implementation, have a look at [WEPopover](https://github.com/ntamas/WEPopover)

Comment: thank you sergio , could you please advise me about popover that appear in image ?

Comment: @Ayaz Alavi: could you be more elaborate and post a new question?